# ImportError: no module named src или почему Pycharm работает, а терминал - нет?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, развертывание

Предположим, есть два скрипта: 
-wsgi.py
и рядом с ним второй, называется controller.py .

wsgi - очень простой, там написано:

```
'from src.dev.controller import app
 'if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(threaded=True)'
```

Запускаю из Pycharm - ок, все работает. 
Захожу в терминал **под тем же виртуальным окружением (virtualenv), что и в настройках PyCharm-a**  - получаю Traceback:
$python wsgi.py

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
from src.dev.controller import app
ImportError: No module named 'src' '
```

я полез разбираться - повторил вот это(там про добавление PYTHONPATH) http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=197830.0 - не сработало.
все **init**.py написаны и лежат пустые во всех папках.

Пытался в wsgi.py дописывать sys.path.insert(0,r'/home/spotapov/testbuild/image-processor/src/dev'
 - тоже не сработало.

Надеюсь на помощь, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если судить по ошибке файл `wsgi.py` не находится в одном каталоге с директорией модулей `src`. Обеспечьте доступность: положите в общую папку или добавьте в sys.path (используйте путь как вы пробовали только окончание сделайте `../image-processor`)

В PyCharm вероятней всего ваш проект оформлен package и он правильно добавляет в PYTHONPATH, `print sys.path` в консоли и в pycharm и сравните.

Comment: Все правильно, как вы и сказали, за исключением истории с sys.path - она не нужна, положил все на самый верх - заработало. Правда, я не знаю почему